# Splitting a file based on text in Python

Tags: python, text, split

I have a file structured as follows:

```
Title = "test.txt"  
variables = x,y,z  
zone height=100m  
x1, y1, z1  
...   
xn, yn, zn  
zone height=020m  
x1, y1, z1  
...  
xn, yn, zn
```

And need to split this into multiple files starting with the the zone height=xxx lines. The name of these output files should be outfile_xxx.txt where the xxx is the height value.

There will not always be only heights to run and so it needs to be able to write an arbitary number of output files based on the number

I have been trying the below and now and it is almost working as planned. I would rather not write the placeholder file for the header but can't think of the easiest way to skip the header rows

```
inp=open(inputfilename)
out=open('zplane_placeholder_for_header.dat','w')

for line in inp:
      if line.startswith("zone"):
        height=line[8:11]
        out.close()
        out=open('zplane'+str(height)+'.dat','w')
      else:
        out.write(line)
out.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Post what you tried....

Comment: The code looks fine (except for 'count' which is not defined and last 'out' which is not closed). What error do you get?

Comment: I think the code looks fine.

Comment: Sorry there is a count definition earlier in file I forgot to open.

What this will do is write the first section before the second zone line but will not write the second section

Comment: Can you post your traceback?

Comment: Also the count is there just as a placeholder until I get the text writing out first

Comment: Do you get any error, or not? If you do, PLEASE, post the traceback :)

Comment: I have made some changes to code and got it almost working as wanted and updated inital question to show

Comment: And is it working now?

Comment: Almost I am looking for a way to skip the first two header lines, and also following the zone line there is another header for each section that I do not want included in the output files

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this to work for me with the following.

```
with open (inputfilename) as f:
    next(f)
    next(f)
    for line in f:
      if line.startswith("zone"):
        height=line[8:11]
        next(f)
        out=open('zplane'+str(height)+'.dat','w')
      else:
        out.write(line)
out.close()
```